# Jackson - Global visibility does not work

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I am trying to globally set **visibility** of getters and setters in Spring web application to my custom **object mapper**. Here is the mapper:

```
public class FieldsObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {
    public FieldsObjectMapper() {
        super();

        setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
        setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
    }
}
```

and this is Spring XML configuration:

```
<bean id="objectMapper"
      class="com.app.FieldsObjectMapper"/>

<bean id="jsonMessageConverter"
      class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="objectMapper" ref="objectMapper"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters" ref="jsonMessageConverter"/>
</bean>
```

What I want to achieve is **JSON deserialization** to object based only on my `@JsonProperty` annotation above fields not by setter or getters.

This is my POJO:

```
public class OrderRequest {
      ...

    @JsonProperty(value = "expiration")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = JsonLocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    private LocalDateTime _expiration;

    public LocalDateTime getExpiration() {
        return _expiration;
    }

    public void setExpiration(LocalDateTime expiration) {
        _expiration = expiration;
    }

      ...
}
```

Deserialization with this setup **doesn't work**, exception is thrown while trying to deserialize `LocalDateTime` because default LocalDateTimeDeserializer is used, not my annotated `JsonLocalDateTimeDeserializer`.

If I put this annotation

```
@JsonAutoDetect(
    setterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE,
    getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
```

locally above the `OrderRequest` class everything works perfectly and JSON gets deserialized into the object **correctly**.

Am I setting something wrong or there is a pullback somewhere else?

Thanks for help in advance.

P.S.: I am using Jackson **2.6.0** and Spring **4.2**

Comment: Small comment, why don't you use the `@JsonCreator` annotation to build a correct object? Using annotation on getters and setters is a bad practice (I assume you know this as you're trying to avoid it), and I think you can achieve the same you want to do here in an easier way by using a constructor.

Comment: That's right but the effect is the same, furthermore I have to write one more annotation and more code :-/

Comment: I don't think visibility should matter at all; your `@JsonDeserialize(using=)` should take effect regardless of visibility settings; especially since you are using `@JsonProperty`. But if you can build a self-contained example (outside of Spring), it may make sense to file an issue against `jackson-databind` -- your custom deserializer should be used for that property.

Comment: I don't know, when I use `@JsonProperty` with `@JsonDeserialize` and put `@JsonIgnore` above **setter** (_without `@JsonAutoDetect` above class_) it works and my deserializer is used, but when I remove it the default one is used not mine.

Comment: Are you using `<mvc:annotation-driven />`